# Loop to save multiple files

Tags: stata

I would like to import multiple Excel files from a folder into Stata and save them as separate dta files. Each year has 4 quarters worth of sheets. Within each quarter, there are 60 sheets. I want to import each sheet individually.

E.g.

> 2004 Quarter 1 has Sheet 1- to save into 2004Q11.dta
>
> 2004 Quarter 1 has Sheet60- to save into 2004Q60

Is there a way to write it in a loop for speed?

```
local quarter q1 q2 q3 q4
local i= 0
foreach q of quarter {
    foreach a of numlist 1/10 {
        import excel "2012`quarter'data", sheet("Sheet`i'") clear
        save "2012`quarter'`i'.dta", replace
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
local quarter q1 q2 q3 q4
local i= 0
foreach q of quarter{
foreach a of numlist 1/10 {
import excel "2012`quarter'data", sheet("Sheet`i'") clear
save "2012`quarter'`i'.dta", replace
}
}
```

Some confusions here about

1. how to use `foreach`: the `of` syntax requires a keyword. `foreach` won't look inside a local macro without `local` as a keyword.
2. using a loop index inside the loop. You set `i` to 1 and ignore your loop index. That's legal but presumably not what you want, as otherwise you're just reading in the same sheet 10 times.

You *could* use `foreach` here, but both your loops are easier with `forval`.

```
forval q = 1/4 {
    forval a = 1/60 {
        import excel "2012q`q'data", sheet("Sheet`a'") clear
        save "2012q`q'`a'.dta", replace
     }
}
```

Necessarily I can't check this. Why you write 10 not 60 is not clear.

Producing 240 separate .dta files will just leave you needing a strategy on how to combine them, but that would be a separate question.

Comment: Thank you, I was running 1/10 to give it a trial run. Thank you for the forval tip, I have been looking from old codes the previous guy wrote and it was all "foreach". :)